# IntelliJ doesn't see JDK in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, intellij-idea, jdk, openjdk

I installed IntelliJ 2019.1 on Linux Mint, but it doesn't recognize the JDK. I'm used to it automatically detecting it.

I have tried:

- Manually adding the JDK. 
  I go to Project Structure and try to select an SDK; it says "NO SDK". 
  I try to add one and it opens a dialog window
  where I should select the JDK's location. 
  I want to select `/usr/bin/java` or `/usr/lib/jvm/`,
  but when I browse into `/usr` and expand `bin`, it shows `bin` as empty. 
  Likewise, it doesn't see the `jvm/` directory within `/usr/lib`.
- Removing IntelliJ, purging all traces of java from my system, reinstalling OpenJDK 8 using apt, restarting, then reinstalling IntelliJ.
- Tried following the steps at [the "IntelliJ can't find JDK" FAQ](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=287080)
  (at Linux Mint Forums), but the repo was taken down on the 16th of April.

I need to specifically use version 8, preferably OpenJDK not Oracle (existing project with other team members who would like us all using the JDK).

`java -version` returns

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

`whereis java` returns

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

`echo $JAVA_HOME` returns nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by “selecting `/xxx/xxx/xxxx`”?

Comment: I go to Project Structure, try to select an SDK, it says NO SDK, I try to add one, it opens a window where I should select the JDK's location, I expand usr then expand bin and bin shows as empty. Please let me know if there's any specific information I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is your intellij might be a flatpak install which cant access certain directories like lib, bin, usr

this might help: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003479520-Intellij-doesn-t-see-JDK-in-Linux-Mint#community_comment_360001644240

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1166208)